# Split list in to sublist in C#

Tags: c#

I like to split the list in to multiple list, list contains GUID's. For an example, if main list contains 130 GUID's, I have kept threshold as 50, so it should return, 3 list, 1st and 2nd list should contain 50 list each and third list will have 30 GUID's.

How can we do it? Please help me out!!

Comment: I highly recommend you search the site before posting questions. The related list of questions for this question shows many duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. here I'm using string for demo, you can use your `guid`.

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var threashold = 2;
var total = list.Count();

var taken = 0;
var sublists = new List<List<string>>(); //your final result
while (taken < total)
{
    var sublst = list.Skip(taken)
        .Take(taken + threashold > total ? total - taken : threashold)
        .ToList();
    taken += threashold;
    sublists.Add(sublst);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arghya, Another way to do is, using MoreLinq
...
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Guid>> result = enumerableGuids.Batch(50);

Answer (score 0):

You can use following LINQ query:

```
 // your sample list
 List<Guid> guids = Enumerable.Range(0, 130).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

 List<List<Guid>> splitted = guids
    .Select((guid, index) => new { guid, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 50)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.guid).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

The essential method is `Enumerable.GroupBy` which groups them by index / 50. because integer division truncates the fractional part you get groups of 50.

Comment: Thanks Tim, It's working, Appreciated but Another way to do is, it may be helpful, using MoreLinq
...
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Guid>> result = enumerableGuids.Batch(50);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MoreLinq` written by Jon Skeet:
[google code](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (available on nuget)

The method you are looking for is `Batch`:

```
using MoreLinq
...
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Guid>> result = enumerableGuids.Batch(50);
```

Comment: Hi, It's a perfect way to use it, I have downloaded MoreLinq via Nuget and it works like a charm!!! Thanks much, Appreciated..